# How to transpose background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

Is there a way to transpose a background image with CSS? (By "transpose" I mean that every pixel x,y in the source image ends up as pixel y,x in the background.)

Example

Source image:
[image]
Transposed image:
[image]

Comment: An image describing "transposing" would be great to understand what you mean.

Comment: From your explanation, you mean rotate it 90° ?

Comment: Yes it seems he wants to rotate it 90º "counter clockwise".

Comment: @Bartdude flip it about 45 degree axis. I think it can be done by 90deg rotating *and* v/h flipping.

Comment: You can accomplish the same transformation by rotating 270 degree.

Comment: @JoãoPinho Not really. By v/h flipping I mean vertical OR horizontal flipping, not vertical AND horizontal flipping. Whether it's vertical or horizontal depends on whether the flipping happens before or after the rotation, and whether the rotation is clockwise or anticlockwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result image can in fact be achieved after scaling it around Y axis with factor of `-1` and then applying rotate transform of `-90deg`. Try this:

```
div.transposed {
  -webkit-transform-origin:left top;
  -webkit-transform:scaleY(-1) rotate3d(0,0,1,-90deg);    
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/jcvC2/3/)

Note that we have to rotate `-90deg` instead of `90deg` because we use `scaleY` before, it will turn the positive direction of Y axis from *top-to-bottom* (downwards) to *bottom-to-top* (upwards). In fact `scaleY(-1)` is equal to `rotateX(180deg)`, in 3D, that means the positive direction of Z axis will be inverted (instead of outwards from screen, it will be inwards to the screen), hence the rotating angle should be `-90deg` instead of `90deg` as we might think.

Please test the demo on webkit-based browsers.

Comment: I was going for the same solution +1, but I was adding the background to a pseudo element so the content isn't affected : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6MQ5d/1/

Comment: @web-tiki thanks, I've just thought it was a problem of transforming the background. Also thanks for the demo because I've noticed the difference in quality of the transformed image, it's because of using `transform-origin: 0 0`, by default it is `50%`, couldn't believe that it could affect the transformed image's quality.

Comment: @web-tiki and King King, thanks for your helpful demos. Just `transform:rotate3d(1,1,0,180deg);` does it too!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you want to rotate the image 90 degrees. pixels along x become pixels along y. In CSS3 this is a transform.

```
#myParentElement
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) /* updated to add flip */;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

to do this to a background image you would need to apply the CSS transform to the parent of the element that has the background image. Apply another transform to the element so that its contents are not transformed.

```
#myParentElement
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
#myElement
{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: FlipH;
    -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

Comment: I think this would do the trick if it *also* flips about vertical/horizontal axis. Is it possible to add that operation?

Comment: I am not shure you need all those vendor prefixes, if you check caIuse : http://caniuse.com/transforms2d you will see that `-moz-` isn't used since FF 16 and `-o-` since Opera 12. So I think the only ones you need are `-webkit-` and `-ms-`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. I think the two transforms should appear in the same "css statement" (or whatever it's called) otherwise the second one overwrites the first one. Still, +1 because this was first and would be more browser independent if corrected. Thanks.

Comment: Attach background to parent element then and the child element restores the text or none background information back to normal.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I'm saying is that (for example) `-webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);` seems to overwrite, rather than append to `-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);` but if you put it all into one statement `-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) scaleX(-1);` then it works.

Comment: Yes my bad transforms need to be combined - I'll need to fix my code latter b/c of work.

Answer (score 1):

If by "transpose" you mean [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), it's similar with "rotate 270 deg and reflect vertically" or "rotate 90 deg and reflect horizontally".

There you can find full solution to "rotate background" problem: http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2013/04/css-rotate-background-images.html

After rotating you can reflect image by `transform:scaleY(-1)` or `transform:scaleX(-1)`.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to rotate the background 90 degrees on an element without affecting the element itself:

```
#myelement {
  height: 164px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 79px;
}
#myelement:before {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMRiV.png") no-repeat;
  content: "";
  height: 79px;
  left: -42px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 164px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

and the html code:

```
<div id="myelement">test</div>
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fs4Dz/